# Compute All Possible Paths Given A Distance

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a path finding function below written in Java that needs a little work.

I have an array of pogo sticks that each have their own "jumping distance". For example, a pogo stick that has the value `5` can "jump" (move) 5 spaces. I also have a `totalDistance` variable that holds the amount of distance that needs to be traveled.

A user supplies the input through the keyboard where the first integer is the distance, and the remaining integers are the pogo stick distances. The same pogo stick may be used as many times as needed and likewise, pogo sticks with a movement distance > totalDistance are not needed.

My algorithm almost works as desired, although it skips certain combinations due to the iterations of the loop finding a different algorithm first, thus ignoring the potential for other paths.

**I need to essentially check to see if a path has already been computed and then ignore the current iteration of pogo stick and move to the next one.**

Can anybody help with this? Below is my algorithm to find the paths.

```
/*
 * First integer in input
 */
int totalDistance;

/*
 * The remaining integers in the input
 */
ArrayList<Integer> pogoSticks = new ArrayList<Integer>();


private void findPaths() {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> possibleSticks = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < pogoSticks.size(); i++) {

        int pogoStickDistance = pogoSticks.get(i);

        if (pogoStickDistance == totalDistance) {
            if (!possibleSticks.contains(new ArrayList<Integer>(pogoStickDistance))) {
                ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                list.add(pogoStickDistance);
                possibleSticks.add(list);
            }
        } else if (pogoStickDistance < totalDistance) {
            int remainingDistance = totalDistance;
            ArrayList<Integer> possibleSubSticks = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            possibleSubSticks.add(pogoStickDistance);
            remainingDistance -= pogoStickDistance;

            for (int j = 0; j < pogoSticks.size(); j++) {

                int pogoStickDistance1 = pogoSticks.get(j);
                if (pogoStickDistance1 == remainingDistance) {
                    System.out.println(remainingDistance);
                    possibleSubSticks.add(pogoStickDistance1);

                    possibleSticks.add(possibleSubSticks);
                    break;
                } else if (pogoStickDistance1 < remainingDistance) {
                    possibleSubSticks.add(pogoStickDistance1);
                    remainingDistance -= pogoStickDistance1;
                }

                if (j == (pogoSticks.size() - 1) && pogoStickDistance1 != remainingDistance) {
                    j = 0;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    System.out.println(possibleSticks);
}
```

Output:

```
Enter input: 5 5 10 1 3
[[5], [1, 1, 3], [3, 1, 1]]
```

The first 5 is the distance, the other numbers are pogo stick distances.

I am missing paths such as `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]`, and `[1, 3, 1]`

Comment: If I am not wrong, you have another similar question here [Calculate all possible paths](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35144627/calculate-all-possible-paths-algorithm)?

Comment: Yea, this one is much more updated though.

Comment: If that's the case, why don't you just update the previous one? or delete the previous is also possible

Comment: I thought making a new post might help get feedback. I can update the old one, I'm just afraid no one will see it.

Comment: You don't need to worry about that, this website has a mechanism to promote modified/updated answer. If you are still worried, you can just delete the previous one. IMO, double post will cause confusion and may waste other effort when they try to answer already-answered question.

Comment: I have deleted the original. Thanks for the information. Any chance you know what I'm missing here?

Comment: Np, this problem is similar to **coin change** problem, you can search for that for more information. Here is one [example](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Coin_Change)

Comment: Looks like there are a lot of missing things in your code, consider this case, when remaining distance is 5, and pogo sticks are [3, 2] , so there are two possible paths : from 5 -> 2 -> 3 or 5-> 3 -> 2, but, your inner for loop can only consider one path 5->3->2.

Comment: Ideally it should recognize the 3->2 path and then restart the loop, ignore the 3 and then take the 2 and then the 3 in the next iteration. I looked at the coin change problem but I am still confused with how they made theirs to allow this scenario.

Comment: They do it simply by using recursion. I think, you have to put more effort on this, whenever you don't know how to express your logic into code, also means, your programming skill needs to improve, in order to solve the problem.

Comment: Here's a hint: Suppose you have 3 pogo sticks, with jump distances 3, 4 and 6, and the distance is 20.  In every path, the first jump must be of distance 3, 4 or 6.  If it's 3, then the remainder of the path consists of some way of jumping a distance of 17; likewise, if it's 4, the remainder of the path consists of some way of jumping a distance of 16, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the binary tree of exploration of all possible paths to your solution here[image]

if totaldistance=5 and you have two kinds of sticks of 1 and 3 then you can see the paths that have reached solution and the paths that already exceeded solution and need not be considered further.

This problem can be solved with an exploration of the tree (it could be n-ary tree in your case of you have n kinds of sticks). The solution typically can be found by breadth-first-search or depth-first-search - you need to use some kind of Queue or Stack for that. So you need to scrap your solution and start over.